# Nmap through Burp ¿?

Tags: nmap, http-proxy, burp-suite

I know nmap and burp work at different levels, but in the same way, metasploit allows to set either an http or socks4 proxy, and I know and have used proxychains with Burp also.

But what I want is to see how the requests are done when using a HTTP `http-wordpress-brute`script to an server on port 443, too bad because if it would have been to a port 80, at least I could have seen non-encrypted data with Wireshark. Anyways, I prefer to use Burp.

Is it possible to carry this out in some way¿?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you want to use nmap through burp, or do you want to use http-wordpress-brute through burp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instruct nmap to use a proxy, in this case you will want to use Burp as your proxy. More information here: https://nmap.org/book/ncat-man-proxy-options.html

edit: 
this should work for you seamlesly:

```
--proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Assuming 127.0.0.1 is the IP of your burp proxy and its port is 8080

Comment: FYI, I had to specify `--proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080` Otherwise, nmap would exit saying my proxy protocol was invalid.